# sending multiple ajax requests not getting expected repsonse

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

so i have a javascript function that submits individual submissions from a form to a phpfile (processFeedback.php) that adds each submission to an array.  then once the array is filled the array is passed back to the ajax callback (i think that's the proper terminology).  if the array is passed back then the array gets passed to another php file (insertFeedback.php) that will insert the data into the database accordingly.

the entire site and all the scripts work perfectly, as in the array is getting filled and passed back to the ajax call correctly.  but i'm getting an error message on the (insertFeedback.php) file call.  as of right now the insertFeedback.php file does nothing but insert my database connect file.  there is no return or anything being done on this page.  i have tried several options, setting various arrays and json_encoding them with the same response every time.  but i can't get a set answer as to why as the jqxhr.error sends me to a jquery fuction that i do not as of yet understand, and there is no jqxhr.responseText (both of which i use regularly for debugging.

here's my function:

```
function prepareData(cont, sect) {

    var sentData = {'choice': cont, 'section': sect};
    var addSession = $.post('processFeedback.php', sentData, null, 'json');
    addSession.done(function (fbData) {
        console.log('success:  ' + fbData);
        action = fbData.action;

        if (fbData.status) {
            receivedData = fbData.data;
            console.log('receivedData.age:  ' + receivedData.age);
            var insertData = $.post('insertFeedback.php', receivedData);
            insertData.done(function(insertData) {
                console.log('from insert page:  ' + insertData);
            });
            insertData.fail(function(noInsertData) {
                console.log('failed at insert page:  ' + noInsertData);
            })
        }

        if (!fbData.status) {
            console.log('form not complete yet');
        }

        eval(action);
    });
    addSession.fail(function (a, b, c) {
        console.log('failure: ' + a.reponseText);
    });
}
```

i have been starting at this code for hours, so i know this is going to be a painstakingly simple answer.  most likely just messing up my variables somewhere along the way.  but any help with why the insertData function keeps failing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with $.post, I usually use $.ajax, so I can't really tell if your syntax is correct. What you could do is insert console logs in every line and see which line your code is breaking?

Comment: Well my guess is `receivedData = fbData.data;` is not an object. Can you try with `{receivedData}` ie `$.post('insertFeedback.php', {receivedData});` . Just to check I am right :)

Comment: the only difference is the way the post is sent... my way sends each line as "key value... your way with the brackets sends each line as receivedData[key] value  hope that makes sense

Comment: i even tired seperating second .post in it's own function... still same results